# How to pass this string C++

Tags: c++

So I got this assignment and I have everything working perfectly except calling this one function that is supposed to format the email string.  If not calling this function, I can print it exactly the way the professor says it is supposed to be. However, with calling this function, I can't seem to get it to return the information and print it.  Can anyone help me out with this? I have spent an unfortunate amount of hours trying to get this one thing worked out.

```
//Function Prototypes
std::string FormatEmailString(std::string from, std::string to, std::string subject, std::string msg);
std::string GetInboxFile(std::string username);
std::string GetLine(std::istream & sin);


int main()
{
    std::string email;
    std::string from;
    std::string to;
    std::string subject;
    std::string msg;

    std::ifstream fin;
    std::ofstream fout;
    std::string user1;

    fin.open(user1 + "-inbox.txt", std::ios::in);

    while (fin.eof() == false) // I know fin.eof is not a good method to use.  
    {                          // I tried while(fin) but it lets extra "From:" "To"...

        email = GetLine(fin); //GetLine is a function call to getline.
        from = GetLine(fin);
        to = GetLine(fin);
        subject = GetLine(fin);
        msg = GetLine(fin);

        std::string formatted = FormatEmailString(from, to, subject, msg);
        fout << formatted;

    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    fin.close();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

std::string FormatEmailString(std::string from, std::string to, std::string subject, std::string msg)
{

    std::ostringstream out;
    std::ifstream fin;

    std::string user1;
    fin.open(user1 + "-inbox.txt", std::ios::in);

    out << std::endl;
    out << "From: " << from << std::endl;
    out << "To: " << to << std::endl;
    out << "Subject: " << subject << std::endl;
    out << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;

    fin.close();
    return out.str();

}//END FormatEmailString

std::string GetLine(std::istream & sin)
{

    std::string s;
    std::getline(sin, s);
    return s;

}//END GetLine

//FROM user1-inbox.txt TEXT FILE:
 #email             //This Line not printed
 abc                //FROM
 user1              //TO
 hello              //Subject
 How about lunch?   //Message
 #email             //This line not printed
 abc                //From
 user1              //To
 Join the Dark Side //Subject
 We have cookies!   //Message
 //END TEXT FILE
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What result do you get?

Comment: The expected result is to print out the text file as:

From: abc
To: user1
Subject: Join the Dark Side
Message: We have cookies!

I am getting a blank or a freeze up every time that I call the function FormatEmailString( from, to, subject, msg).

Comment: Why did you make your own `getline`?

Comment: `std::string user1;` constructs `user1` as an empty string. So what file are you really opening?

Comment: `fin.open(user1 + "-inbox.txt", std::ios::in);` what's the point of this?  You don't ever fetch data from `fin` or write data to `user1`, meaning you always load the file `"-inbox.txt"`.

Comment: That's what the professor called for, wanted a getline function.

Comment: I was showing you quickly that I was opening a file with the name user1-inbox.txt.  I have it different in my program.  Just trying to figure out the main issue between printing the out the put.  Not sure if I am passing the string correctly or what issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

you are not opening file which you want to write into.
your `fout` is used only in two places... in declaration and then u are writing into it.

Comment: dude, its an answer to the question- reason of the bug. isn't it?

Comment: My bad..removed my comment.